# Oracle 10 MERGE performance

Tags: oracle, merge

I had a very strange performance related problem with `MERGE` in Oracle 10. In a few words, I have a stored procedure that calculates and stores user rank based on her activity in the system and contains just one `MERGE` statement:

```
MERGE INTO user_ranks target USING 
([complex query that returns rank_id and user_id])src ON 
(src.user_id = target.user_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET target.rank_id = src.rank_id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (target.user_id, target.rank_id)
  VALUES (src.user_id, src.rank_id);

// user_ranks table structure:
CREATE TABLE user_ranks (user_id INT NOT NULL 
PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX (CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_uid_uranks ON user_ranks(user_id)),
rank_id INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_uid_uranks FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id),
CONSTRAINT FK_rid_uranks FOREIGN KEY(rank_id) REFERENCES ranks(id));
// no index on rank_id - intentionally, ranks table is a lookup with 
// a very few records and no delete/update allowed
```

The subquery which is used as a source for `MERGE` returns at most 1 record (user_id is passed as parameter to the procedure). It's quite expensive but execution time is acceptable (1-1.2 sec). The problem is that `MERGE` execution time hikes to more than 40 seconds, and I have no clue why. I tried using `LEADING` hint with no success. But if I split the statement into 2 parts, first one - run `SELECT` subquery and store result(rank_id) into variable and then merge - `MERGE ... USING (SELECT user_id, rank_id FROM DUAL)src ...` everything works just fine. From what I read, there are known issues with Oracle's `MERGE`, but they are mostly related to triggers (no triggers in my case). It also says that `MERGE` works slower than combination of `INSERT` and `UPDATE`, but I believe the "normal" difference is around 5-10%, not 30 times...

I'm trying to understand what I did wrong... Thanks for your suggestions.

**Update**
Execution plan is quite long to post it here, in short : subquery cost by itself is 12737, with `merge` - 76305. Stats output for `merge` :

### > Statistics

```
         108  recursive calls
           4  db block gets
    45630447  consistent gets
       24905  physical reads
           0  redo size
         620  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        1183  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
           2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
           2  sorts (memory)
           0  sorts (disk)
```

subquery alone :

### > Statistics

```
           8  recursive calls
           0  db block gets
          34  consistent gets
           0  physical reads
           0  redo size
         558  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
         234  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
           1  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
           1  sorts (memory)
           0  sorts (disk)
```

Comment: please post the execution plan

Comment: +1 to get the query plan. Wild guess: the merge might not detect that the complex query returns only 1 row, so it does a full scan of `user_ranks` to drive a hash join - you might fix this by adding `WHERE ROWNUM = 1` to your complex query, so that the optimiser knows you expect only 1 row always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've [set up SQL*Plus autotrace](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch8.htm#i1037226) it would be a matter of seconds to see which part of the actual execution plan has caused the most physical and logical I/O and used the most memory.

Note that the information you get using this method is much more precise than a simple `explain plan`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still don't know why it works this way, but at least I get more information. Since there is a workaround (2 statements , `select` + `merge`), I'm ok from practical point of view.